# PHPWord Download Error (the office open XML file cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents)

Tags: php, xml, phpword

I am having a problem with my PHPWord implementation. I am building a feature that will allow users to download content to word and am using PHPWord for this. However, after the document is downloaded I am getting an error while opening:

> the office open XML file cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents

I'm only able to preview the contents of the word file after the accepting the recovery procedure, which I think is not something user friendly.

Here is my PHP code.

```
 <?php
    require_once '../assets/vendor/autoload.php';

        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, "Content");

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
        header("Content-Type: application/docx");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.docx"');

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $objWriter->save('test.docx');


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common issue for PHPWord.Hope the following code fragment will solve your problem as it solves mine.

```
$doc_filename = "Test_Report_". date("d-m-Y").".docx";

// Save file
// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');

$temp_file_uri = tempnam('', 'anytext');
$objWriter->save($temp_file_uri);

//download code
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/docx");//header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$doc_filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($temp_file_uri));
readfile($temp_file_uri);
unlink($temp_file_uri); // deletes the temporary file
exit;
```

-Thanks